# Generic type definition to unmarshal struct as slice

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have an API that often returns arrays as an object that contains an array. Take the example below:

```json
{
  "items": {
    "number": 3,
    "item": [
      { ... } // Not relevant
    ]
  }
}
```

The API does this in dozens of places with a different name each time. It is guaranteed that when this occurs there are only two keys: one of them being `number` and the other being the array.

This makes the resulting structs rather unpleasant to work with, as you constantly have to navigate through levels of unnecessary fields.

I essentially want my Go interface to pretend it had this format instead:

```json
{
  "items": [
    { ... } // Not relevant
  ]
}
```

One option is to write a custom `UnmarshalJSON` function for every single occurrence, but this seems cumbersome, especially considering this appears in nearly every struct. The solution I had in mind is a generic type that can handle it on its own.

My current attempt is below:

```golang
// NestedArray tries to pull an unnecessarily nested array upwards
type NestedArray[T any] []T

func (n *NestedArray[T]) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    // First unmarshal into a map
    target := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Then find the nested array (key is unknown, so go off of the type instead)
    var sliceVal interface{}
    for k, v := range target {
        if k == "number" {
            continue
        }

        rt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
        if rt.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            sliceVal = v
            break
        }
    }

    // Missing or empty, doesn't matter - set the result to nil
    if sliceVal == nil {
        *n = nil
        return nil
    }

    // Turn back into JSON and parse into correct target
    sliceJSON, err := json.Marshal(sliceVal)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(sliceJSON, n)  // Error occurs here
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Using it as follows:

```golang
type Item struct {
  // Not relevant
}

type Root struct {
    // Use generic type to parse a JSON object into its nested array
    Items NestedArray[Item] `json:"items,omitempty"`
}
```

Results in the following error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Root.items of type map[string]interface{}
```

The biggest part of `UnmarshalJSON` code seems correct, as my debugger shows me that `sliceVal` is what I'd expect it to be. It errors when unmarshalling back into the `NestedArray[T]` type.

What could be the solution to this problem? Is there a better way to go about it than what I'm currently doing? This seemed the cleanest to me but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method NestedArray[T].UnmarshalJSON calls itself recursively. The inner call throws an error because it's expecting a JSON object in `bytes`, but it received a JSON array. Fix by unmarshalling to a `[]T` instead of a `NestedArray[T]`.

Unrelated to the error, the method NestedArray[T].UnmarshalJSON does some unnecessary encoding and decoding.  Fix by using [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage).

Here's the code with both fixes:

```
func (n *NestedArray[T]) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    // First unmarshal into a map
    var target map[string]json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Then find the nested array (key is unknown, so go off of the type instead)
    var array json.RawMessage
    for k, v := range target {
        if k == "number" {
            continue
        }
        if len(v) > 0 && v[0] == '[' {
            array = v
            break
        }
    }

    // Missing or empty, doesn't matter - set the result to nil
    if array == nil {
        *n = nil
        return nil
    }

    // Avoid recursive call to this method by unmarshalling to a []T.
    var v []T
    err = json.Unmarshal(array, &v)
    *n = v
    return err
}
```

[Run the code on the playground!](https://go.dev/play/p/qmhgptf02Bp).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `RawMessage`. Will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the JSON looking for the array.  Decode each array element and append to the receiver.

```
func (n *NestedArray[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    d := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
    t, err := d.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if t != json.Delim('{') {
        return errors.New("object expected")
    }
    for d.More() {
        // skip key
        _, err = d.Token()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // Is it an JSON array?
        t, err = d.Token()
        if t == json.Delim('[') {
            // Decode the array.
            for d.More() {
                var v T
                err := d.Decode(&v)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                *n = append(*n, v)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/lLFjJpr404W

The question's title is "Generic type alias to unmarshal struct as slice", but here is not a [type alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) in the question.  A better title for the question is "Generic type definition to unmarshal struct as slice".

Comment: As mentioned in the post multiple times, the key is unknown. This pattern occurs in multiple places, each of them having a different key. I want a generic way to do it. Yours calls it `item` which only works for the specific case in my example, but not all the others.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. In which aspects is this better or worse than what I posted myself as the answer?

Comment: I was unaware of the other answer at the time I updated this answer.  Here's my comparison now that I've seen the other answer: The other answer unmarshals, marshals and unmarshals again. This answer unmarshals once.

Answer (score 0):

I got it it work by making the *final* unmarshal use an intermediary variable as opposed to the receiver of the method.

```golang
    // ...
    // Turn back into JSON and parse correctly
    sliceJSON, err := json.Marshal(sliceVal)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Instead of using n here, create a new variable and use that instead
    var result []T

    err = json.Unmarshal(sliceJSON, &result)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Then, assign that to the receiver
    *n = result
```